# Java Selenium Drop down menu Options

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am using selenium for a project. I want my program to interact with a dropdown menu. At times my desired selection will not be present in the dropdown menu. In that case I would like to select a different dropdown element. How do I work around the scenario in which the desired selection is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Select** class in Selenium. You can add **WebElements** from dropdown into List and select whatever element is desired(by Name, by index ...)

Here is the documentation: [Select Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

Answer (score 0):

I just tell the drive to execute some JQuery when working with dropdown

```
Common.executeScript(driver,"$('#dropdown').click()");
Common.executeScript(driver,"$('#dropdown').find('option:last').click()");
```